# Foreign language entries appearing in Safari context menu

Tags: safari, language, shortcut-menu

I am getting some foreign language (Portuguese?) items appearing in my Safari 5.1.5 context menu, when I right-click on an element in a page (see below). My OSX 10.7.3 language is set to English. I have only 2 plugins enabled (AdBlock and UK Search), neither of which has caused problems before or coincided with this appearing.

Why is this happening, and how do I remove or translate these menu entries?

[image: Safari context menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to system preferences/language & text/language and using the Edit button to uncheck the box for Portuguese and restarting.

There are many reports of such mixed localization bugs in 10.7.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I wasn't aware of these localization bugs. Not something you want to see what with all the recent Mac virus news!